# How to manually add an android API to SDK manager?

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator

I want to emulate an android phone on 4.2.2, whereas SDK only have the API 22 (5.1.1) available.

I know i can download it with the SDK manager but i have no acces to internet on this computer.

So is it possible to manually download android 4.4.2 and add it to SDK ?

Comment: you can put the sdk manager on another computer then download it onto that one then copy it over i suppose

Comment: The folder is pretty big (4Go), i don't know where exactly in the folder the 5.1.1 API is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it. Basically you need to copy and paste the already downloaded files from associate folders such as `platforms`. But make sure you copy everything else it will shown as broken.

Answer (score 2):

Download the SDK from another computer. The SDK are stored in $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/platforms

After that, copy the Sdk back to your computer

Answer (score 1):

Download the API you want on another computer. Then simply go to your SDK folder. You will find a folder called `platforms`. Copy that folder to your other computer in your SDK folder.